# Does Moqui framework 2.0 Still support Mutli-tenency

Tags: moqui

I would like to use the Moqui framework  2.0 for next project which should be SaaS based model.Multi-tenent(Seperate database for each client). Please confirm does it still support Multi-tenency.

So that i will kick off my project implmentation with Moqui framework 2.0 next genertion Entprise framwork.

Thanks in advance.
Nyamath ullakhan

Answer (score 1):

The old multi-tenant functionality in Moqui Framework has been deprecated in 2.0.0 by the multi-instance features. The general idea is that instead of running multiple tenants in a single application server instance there are tools to manage multiple instances running in their own containers. In both approaches a separate database is used for each tenant or instance.

There are many reasons for this, and a lot of discussion about it in the Moqui Ecosystem group on LinkedIn. The main benefits of separate instances, which can be in containers or VM instances, are all related to the more complete segregation for different organizations. There are no longer issues with having to be careful about code (even templates) used in each instance.

There is also no longer the staggering complexity of managing segregated caches, ElasticSearch indexes, etc, etc per tenant. This involved thousands of lines of code and dramatically limited the modularity of the framework. For example the multi-tenant complexity made it much more difficult to use alternative tools for searching and other things because they all had to be tenant-aware.

The OOTB functionality in Moqui Framework 2.0.0 supports multiple instances using Docker containers. The multi-instance management is done through a series of service interfaces so that other container or virtual machine infrastructure can be integrated for more automated management. Automated management isn't required for this either, manual provisioning and such can be done without these features of Moqui Framework or through the huge number of other tools that are more generic for managing and monitoring instances.

There is an article about the Docker-based multi-instance configuration and management on LinkedIn here:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/multi-instance-moqui-docker-david-e-jones

Comment: The link to the above article does not work, even when signed in to LinkedIn. It would be really great to be able to access it somewhere. Thanks.